# Infiite sum of trignometry series .

Tags: trigonometry

[image]

In the solution given how they got the circled term .

I could not understand that as it contain **infinite series**

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2125682/to-prove-tana-2-tan2a-4-tan4a-8-cot8a-cota

Comment: This term is zero.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [To prove $ \tan(A) + 2 \tan(2A) +4\tan4A + 8 \cot8A =\cot(A) $](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2125682/to-prove-tana-2-tan2a-4-tan4a-8-cot8a-cota)

Comment: @skyking no it is not similiar to that

Comment: @labbhattacharjee that question does not contain infinite series.

Comment: @Koolman, Did u get the answer?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee now I am more confused . Totally blank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use the identity $\tan x = \cot x - 2\cot 2x$. That is $2^{-k}\tan 2^{-k}x = 2^{-k}\cot x - 2^{-(k-1)}\cot 2^{-(k-1)}x$ so terms will cancel. To put it more formally:

Let $S_n = \sum_1^n 2^{-k} \tan 2^{-k}x$. Now assume that $S_n = -\cot x + 2^{-1}\cot 2^{-n}x$ then we have:

$$S_{n+1} = S_n + 2^{-(n+1)}\tan 2^{-(n+1)}x 
= -\cot x + 2^{-1}\cot 2^{-n}x + 2^{-(n+1)}\left(\cot 2^{-(n+1)}x - 2\cot 2^{-n}x\right)\\
= -\cot x + 2^{-(n+1)}\cot 2^{-n(+1)}x
$$

Also we see that.

$S_1 = {1\over 2}\tan{x\over 2} = {1\over2}\left(\cot {x\over 2} - 2\cot 
x\right) = -\cot x+2^{-1}\cot 2^{-1}x$$

This by induction shows that $S_n = -\cot x + 2^{-1}\cot 2^{-n}x$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$.

The only part where infinity is involved now is to realize that $\sum_1^\infty 2^{-k} \tan 2^{-k}x$ is indeed $\lim S_n$. If you're only require it to converge conditionally it surely is since $S_n$ is the partial sums. If you require absolute convergence you can observe that $0<2^{-k}\tan x/2^k < 2^{-k}\tan x/2 < 2^{-k}$ in the interval, which is enough to have uniform and absolute convergence.