# Homework Problem on Integration

Tags: definite-integrals

$g(x)= \tan(x)+ 2\tan 2x + 4\tan 4x + 8\cot 8x$

and $f(x) = (7\tan^{6} x -3\tan^{2} x) \dfrac{1}{g^{2}(x)+1}$;

$x \in \left( 0,\dfrac{\pi}{4} \right)$

Then find 
$\displaystyle
\int_0^\frac{\pi}{4} f(x) dx$ and 
$\displaystyle \int_0^\frac{\pi}{4} xf(x) dx$

Basically, I don't know how to simplify $f(x)$ or substitute anything.

Comment: Check whether I have wrongly edited something.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2125682/to-prove-tana-2-tan2a-4-tan4a-8-cot8a-cota

Comment: i have simplified your term as $${\frac { \left( 4\, \left( \cos \left( x \right)  \right) ^{4}-14\,
 \left( \cos \left( x \right)  \right) ^{2}+7 \right)  \left( \sin
 \left( x \right)  \right) ^{4}}{ \left( \cos \left( x \right) 
 \right) ^{6}}}
$$

Comment: is your Problem solved now?

Comment: i got $\int_0^\frac{\pi}{4} tan^{4}x sec^{2}{x} \frac{7tan^{4}{x} - 3}{(1+tan^{2}{x})^2} dx$